# разбиение строки типа string на части c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Пусть имеется строка вида:

`string input_text = "abc, \aaa rrrrrrr, bbbbbb";`

Символы разделители:

`const string separation = ".:,;()?!/\*& \n\t\v\f\r";`

**задача:**

необходимо разделить данную строку на подстроки, величины которых почти равнораспределенны на каждый поток. будем считать, что потоков в системе N штук.

что я имею ввиду, когда использую термин равнораспределенны? Отвечаю: если разбиение попало на слово, то необходимо двигаться до символа разделителя, чтобы слово не делилось.

Если потоков 3, на выходе будет:

1 abc

2, \

3 aaa

4 rrrrrrr,

5 bbbbbb

Что имею:

```
void MapFunctionCountWord(string input_text) {

    const string separation = ".:,;()?!/\*& \n\t\v\f\r";
    vector<string> cnt;

    for (int i = input_text.find_first_not_of(separation, 0); i != string::npos; i = input_text.find_first_not_of(separation, i)) 
    { int end = input_text.find_first_of(separation, i);
        cnt.push_back(input_text.substr(i, end - i));
        i = end;
    }
}
```

Функция делит строку на слова при помощи символов разделителей, но мне это не подходит, т.к. нужна порция данных для потока

Comment: это ваша задача, но в чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: сейчас добавлю код

Comment: @MaxGacrux нужен не код, а, для начала, ваш вопрос...

Comment: Делите `input_text.size()` на N (получите примерный размер сегмента данных для потока -- L) и ищите разделитель, начиная с этого индекса. Предавайте полученныу пару индексов (начало, конец) в обрабатывающий поток. Потом найдите первый не разделитель (начало для следующего потока) и отступив на L опять ищите разделитель. И т.д. в цикле

Comment: добавил решение, кому может интересно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input_text = "abc, aa=a rrrrrrr, bbbbb \nqq ss aa,a a";
const string separation = ".:,;()?!/\*& \n\t\v\f\r";
vector<string> text;

int i = input_text.size()/5;
int step = i;
int start = 0;
int finish = 0;
    //int end = input_text.find_first_of(separation, i + 1);
cout << input_text.size() << endl;
    
for (i; i < input_text.size(); ++i)
{ 
    if (separation.find(input_text[i]) != string::npos)
    {
        finish = i;
        text.push_back(string(input_text.substr(start, finish - start)));
        start = finish + 1;
        i = start + step - 2;
    }
    if ((input_text.size() - start) < step || i == input_text.size() - 1)
        text.push_back(string(input_text.substr(start, input_text.size() - start )));
}
```